# Tcl/Tk Gridplus2 How to change date format

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am playing with tcl gridplus  date control, and would like to create
date selector entry.

It should have default value of today, and European date format: **dd.mm.yyyy**

I tried:

```
source ../bin/common/gridplus.kit

package require Tk
package require gridplus

namespace import gridplus::*

# Create date delector
gridplus date .dt -selecttoday 1 -dateformat "eu" {
    {DT .dt}
}
pack .dt
```

As a result I got date selector that:
  - do not show default value; 
  - Show date in US format **mm/dd/yyyy**

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of experimentation shows that if you include the command:

```
gridplus set -dateformat eu
```

that you should end up with the correct date format.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not expected that -dateformat should be set on the global level.  What about the other problem ? How to see current date as a default value?

Answer (score 1):

There currently isn't a way to set a default value for a "date" item. It is neccessary to use a gpset command...

```
gpset .dt,dt [clock format [clock seconds] -format "%d.%m.%Y"]
```

...after creating the "date" ietm (assuming "eu" date format).

I am adding options to specify default values in the next (2.7) release - Due in the next week or two.

Best Regards,

=Adrian=

(GRIDPLUS developer)